# Tensorflow Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.0 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

I have

```
$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.__version__)"
1.15.0
```

and

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

with

```
python --version
Python 3.6.9
pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

but I see `CUDA 10.2` from `nvidia-smi`

```
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Nov 17 18:40:54 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2080    On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 32%   42C    P2    56W / 215W |    265MiB /  7979MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1840      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            57MiB |
|    0      1895      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          85MiB |
|    0     29999      C   /usr/bin/python                              109MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can see

```
$ ls /usr/local/
bin  cuda  cuda-10.1  cuda-10.2  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src
```

and in the `.profile` I can see

```
# set PATH for cuda 10.2 installation
if [ -d "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin/" ]; then
    export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
fi
```

so I did override the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

but it does not seem to fix.

```
2020-11-17 18:38:39.470074: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.487544: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3000000000 Hz
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.489215: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x47007e0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.489273: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.494309: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.542010: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.542387: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x4b1bf40 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.542399: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 2080, Compute Capability 7.5
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.542519: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.542788: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
    name: GeForce RTX 2080 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.71
    pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.542872: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.542919: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.543012: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.543059: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcurand.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.543093: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.543125: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.545590: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.545617: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1641] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
    Skipping registering GPU devices...
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.545653: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.545658: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0 
    2020-11-17 18:38:39.545662: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N 
    ['/device:CPU:0', '/device:XLA_CPU:0', '/device:XLA_GPU:0']
```

Comment: Your TF is looking for CUDA 10.0.  You cannot use CUDA 10.1 or CUDA 10.2 as a substitute for that.  Install CUDA 10.0 (you do not need to install or modify your GPU driver) and point your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables to your CUDA 10.0 install.

Comment: @RobertCrovella correct! shall I have to upgrade tensorfllow 2.0 then I suppose.

Comment: so after linking to `.profile` CUDA 10.1 and installing tensorflow `2.3.1` it works ok in shell, but not within Jupyter notebook (it still sees nvcc 9 instead of 10.1)...

Comment: Try to follow these steps to fix the issue.
`sudo apt install --reinstall libcublas10`

add this to ~/.bashrc:
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume the library exists in `/usr/local/lib/libcudart.so.11.0`

1. First active your python virtual environment, something like: `source ./venv/bin/activate`
2. Once your in the virtual environment set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:
   `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`
3. Finally re-run

In my case, Tensor flow was looking for libcudart.so.11.0, the steps above worked for me:

```
devbox1@devbox1:~/onibex/algo$ source ./venv/bin/activate
(venv) devbox1@devbox1:~/onibex/algo$ 


(venv) devbox1@devbox1:~/onibex/algo$  cd /home/devbox1/docs/onibex/wa/data/sprint0/code/algo ; /usr/bin/env /home/devbox1/docs/onibex/wa/data/sprint0/code/algo/venv/bin/python3 /home/devbox1/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.636928669/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 34287 -- /home/devbox1/docs/onibex/wa/data/sprint0/code/algo/quickly_tensor_flow.py 
2021-03-14 00:12:18.588232: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; 


(venv) devbox1@devbox1:~/onibex/algo$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib


(venv) devbox1@devbox1:~/onibex/algo$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-11.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib


(venv) devbox1@devbox1:~/onibex/algo$  cd /home/devbox1/docs/onibex/wa/data/sprint0/code/algo ; /usr/bin/env /home/devbox1/docs/onibex/wa/data/sprint0/code/algo/venv/bin/python3 /home/devbox1/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.636928669/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 34089 -- /home/devbox1/docs/onibex/wa/data/sprint0/code/algo/quickly_tensor_flow.py 
2021-03-14 21:36:49.207430: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
... hello world!

(venv) devbox1@devbox1:~/onibex/algo$
```

Comment: Hello, what if I do not have this specific version of Cuda and would like TF to use another one. In my case, TF is trying to use libcudart.so.11.0 and I have max the libcudart.so.10.2

Comment: @MilosCuculovic, I am also struggling with the same issue. It seems though that the latest TF version doesn't support Cuda 10.2. See here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu under Software requirements. Were you able to solve your issue?

Comment: Hi @cauthon14, you're right. I was able to fix the issue by installing the cuda 11 driver on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In this folder:

/usr/local/lib

You'll find that file but other version, usually more updated, just copy it in the same folder and change the name for the one you need. That worked for me.

example: I had libcudart.so.12
I rename it to libcudart.so.11.0
and now works without errors...

Good luck!!