# W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.0';

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

When I execute some code (from this repo: https://github.com/guicho271828/latplan), I get the following error:

> W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

I have installed **v1.15** of tensorflow (which is mandatory for the project I am running), and to make it compatible with the GPU I am using I also installed "nvidia-tensorflow" and "nvidia-pyindex".

I also tried :

```
conda install -c nvidia cuda-toolkit
```

But it just installed **cuda v11** in the conda env, and the same error appears again.

So, is it possible to install cuda v10 instead of cuda v11 with conda ?

Any idea to go around this issue ?

Thank you

**p.s:** I already have checked other similar issues like this one [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64880546/tensorflow-could-not-load-dynamic-library-libcudart-so-10-0-on-ubuntu-18-04) but it does not solve my problem as I cannot install another cuda version outside a conda environement (I don't have root access)

Comment: You don't really need root access to install cuda (just think of how anaconda is installing cuda without you being root).

Comment: Yes, This could be the reason. Also please check the Tensorflow, Python, Cuda and cuDnn version with this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) to get gpu support enabled. You can follow the instructions mentioned in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) link to install cuda in your conda environment.