# Spacy + GPU gives error: GPU is not accessible. Was the library installed correctly?

Tags: gpu, spacy, cupy

The following code give error:

```
import spacy
spacy.require_gpu()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/new_tsg/training/spacy_train_data/spacy_pipeline.py", line 39, in <module>
    spacy.require_gpu()
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/new_tsg/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thinc/neural/util.py", line 87, in require_gpu
    raise ValueError("GPU is not accessible. Was the library installed correctly?")
ValueError: GPU is not accessible. Was the library installed correctly?
```

My configuration is:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Feb__8_19:08:17_PST_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.105

GeForce RTX 2080 Driver Version: 418.39
```

Spacy v 2.3.5 was installed with cuda 10.1 support by:

pip install --no-cache-dir spacy[cuda101]

What can I try to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

My mistake in this case was in using the CUDA version specified in by `nvidia-smi` instead of `nvcc --version`.

You should use the version specified in `nvcc --version`. I think `nvidia-smi` indicates the maximum possible cuda version supported by your GPU, rather than the actual version that you have installed.

So if **nvcc** says you have version 11.1, then you should install spacy with:

```bash
pip install -U spacy[cuda111]
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by updating cuda 10.1 to latest release:
`CUDA Toolkit 10.1 update2 (Aug 2019)`
... from
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive

```
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

I used the following commands:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/ /"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-10-1
```

... the in last one I used not just `cuda` (like on nvidia-site) but `cuda-10-1`

After that video driver was updated to 455.45.01

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Mon Dec 14 22:14:53 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.45.01    Driver Version: 455.45.01    CUDA Version: 11.1     |

...
```

Update:

On other PC I had similar issue and previous answer didn't help.
After investigation I find out that `cupy` library call `cuda`.
So I installed `cupy-cuda[101]` and executed the following code:

```
import cupy
a = cupy.zeros((5, 5))
```

... and got the `No such file error with libcublas.so.10`
This file was in

```
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
```

... and not in:

```
/usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
```

So I added `/usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib` path to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda-10-1.conf` and execute `ldconfig` - see answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55224016/importerror-libcublas-so-10-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or)