# Why isn't the correct cuda version found?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

My gpu is the following:
[image]

I created an anaconda environment for Tensorflow 2.5, and also installed:

```
conda install cudatoolkit=11.0
```

And I can import TF correctly:

```
>>> import tensorflow
2021-06-18 05:32:13.692309: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
```

However, when I train, GPU is not found, and it reports error:

```
2021-06-18 05:03:33.144517: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-06-18 05:03:33.162190: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-06-18 05:03:33.162266: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-06-18 05:03:33.170892: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-06-18 05:03:33.240856: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-06-18 05:03:33.241084: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.11'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
```

I checked:

```
> ls /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
libcupti.so  libcupti.so.10.0  libcupti.so.10.0.130
```

But I already installed cudatoolkit=11.0. Why doesn't it have it in the lib directory?

Comment: Its complaining about libcusolver.so.11, not about libcupti, not sure why you are checking that library. Find where libcusolver.so.11 is in your system

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy What command could find the libcusolver.so.11?

Comment: Hi@marlon,  you can find it  from installation location .You can either overwrite it with libcupti.so.10.0.130 file or you can add that in your path either through environment variable or through command .   Reference  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64472380/11530462    .Thanks!